# I follow the different step for installing odoo-11 but at the 13th there is an error

Tags: odoo-11

I follow the different step of this plan :

https://www.getopenerp.com/install-odoo-11-on-ubuntu-16-04/#comment-1623

but at the 13th step I have the error :

```
bash: cd: /opt/odoo/odoo: no such file or directory
```

I don't understand why because I follow correctly each step.